# Frida Casting object to List of Strings

Tags: javascript, java, android, frida

I have been trying to print out the contents of a list when hooking an android app with Frida but am not having any luck.

The object I want to hook in Java looks like this

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import java.util.List;

public final class Hello extends HelloParent{

    @JsonIgnore
    public final List sampleList;

}
```

There aren't any getters for this public object so I have to resort to using another object (Let's call the object "Bye")'s method (byeMethodB) to monitor this value.

This is what my frida-script looks like:

```
setTimeout(function() {

    Java.perform(function(){
        
        Java.use("Bye").byeMethodA.implementation = function(){

            try{
                //Returns a Hello object
                var helloObject = Java.cast(this.byeMethodB(),Java.use("Hello"))
                printListContent(Java.cast(helloObject.sampleList,Java.use("java.util.List"))))
            }catch(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
        }

    })
},1000)

function printListContent(list){

    var listIter = list.iterator()
    while(listIter.hasNext()){
        console.log(listIter.next())
    }

}
```

Without casting the "helloObject.sampleList" object to a list, the output looks like this:

```
[object Object]
```

So I am sure it is not null

If I cast using `Java.cast(helloObject.sampleList,Java.use("java.util.List"))`,

I get the following error:

[image: java.util.List]

I have also tried:

`Java.cast(helloObject.sampleList,Java.use("java.util.List<>"))`

[image: java.util.List<>]

(I am pretty sure its a String)
`Java.cast(helloObject.sampleList,Java.use("java.util.List<String>"))`

[image: java.util.List]

`Java.cast(helloObject.sampleList,Java.use("java.util.List<java.lang.String>"))`

[image: java.util.List<java.lang.String>]

`Java.cast(helloObject.sampleList,Java.use("[String"))`

[image: [LString]

`Java.cast(helloObject.sampleList,Java.use("[Ljava.lang.String"))`

[image: [Ljava.lang.String]

It is not going well at all. Would appreciate some help

Comment: Please don't post console output as screen-shot. It is simple text, just copy and paste the relevant parts into your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Frida accessing fields is not identical as in Java. If you execute `helloObject.sampleList` in Frida you are getting the JavaScript object that describes the field, not the field value itself.

If you want the field value you have to execute `helloObject.sampleList.value`.

Therefore the following code should work:

```
Java.cast(helloObject.sampleList.value, Java.use("java.util.List"));
```

Generics only exists at compile time but frida is working at run-time. Therefore `java.util.List<>` and the other class names with angle bracket will never work.

Comment: It's working now! Appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer is good, a problem I had is that I had to call `toArray()` on the casted param

```
somehook["getUrlList"].implementation = function () {
    console.log(`UrlModel.getUrlList is called`);
    let result = this["getUrlList"]();
    var stringArray = Java.cast(result, Java.use('java.util.List')).toArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        console.log('String[' + i + ']: ' + stringArray[i]);
    }
    return result;
};
```

Comment: So directly accessing the list using `.size()` instead of `.length` and accessing the element using `.get(i)` instead of `[i]` did not work?